# How do I spin a VM in a service project with an already configured shared VPC residing in a host project using terraform on GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I have managed to create a shared VPC in a host project and shared it with a service project.

The challenge is now to deploy a VM in the service project. It's easy to use the console UI for a few servers but I have to spin 30 servers and would like to use terraform to do that.

When I reference the shared network I get the following error:

> Error 400: Invalid value for field 'resource.networkInterfaces[0].network':

How can I deploy a VM in a service project referencing an already created shared VPC in the host project?

Comment: Can you share your Terraform code? Ideally as a [mcve] that when ran produces the same error.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try using the import command to update your state file:
https://www.terraform.io/docs/import/index.html